# Power query M in Power BI IF statement does not recognize AND

Tags: if-statement, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to write a Power M query in Power BI. It is an **IF **statement that has **2** conditions. Both conditions work as intended, but when I use **AND **between them nothing is happening and there are no errors too:

`if Date.WeekOfYear([firstloadingdate])>=52 and Date.Year([firstloadingdate])=Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()) then Number.ToText([LoadingYearC]-1) & "," & [LoadingWeek] else Number.ToText([LoadingYearC]) & "," & [LoadingWeek]`

I want to check if week number is >=52 and current year is = to year from a date field. If true, then subtract 1 from year, if not then just show the year.

But it doesnt work with the AND. Separately the conditions work correctly...

EDIT: Here is an image of the data record which should be changing, but is not.
[image]

Comment: You *have* verified that values exist for which both conditions are `true` at the same time, right?

Comment: code looks fine. You must not have an instance when both are true

Comment: @JeroenMostert I edited the topic with an image of the record that abides by both rules.

Comment: Date.WeekOfYear(1/1/2023) = 1 which is not >=52, so that will evaluate as FALSE

Comment: @horseyride I am not using the US standard for week numbering. I use the European ISO standard and 2022 ends with 52 weeks. Its just that in M query I cannot say which format the week should be. So 01.01.2023 is week 52 ISO standard or week 53 US standard. So if the rule is >=52 then i have both options covered.

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://gist.github.com/r-k-b/18d898e5eed786c9240e3804b167a5ca). `Date.WeekOfYear` cannot be compelled to calculate ISO week numbers, and worse, if you don't specify the second parameter even the first day of the week is culture-dependent. Calculating the ISO week number in M may be a little involved, but I'd take it over workarounds like this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert why does it matter though? If week number is equal or higher than 52 then it shouldn't matter that I do not specify which format it is.

Comment: So is it? What is `Date.WeekOfYear([firstloadingdate])` when extracted to a separate column? Because on my machine, that's `1`.

Comment: Post what your machine calculates as Date.WeekOfYear(#date(2023,1,1))

Comment: @JeroenMostert Okay that is strange. Why is it shown as 1... Shouldn't it still be 53? Thats a sunday, last day... This means that this formula counts WeekOfYear based on 1st day of year, which is not part of neither the US nor the EU norm...

Comment: `Date.WeekOfYear`'s optional second parameter indicates when the week begins, which has a "culture-specific default". Note that it does not indicate what day the year should be considered to be starting at (as in, the first week containing day X), just when weeks begin. Hence my remark that I'd just use a function to calculate the ISO week rather than try to puzzle this out.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I used one of my other colums, where I have week number come from SQL source. When I replaced the firstloadingdate field everything works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Date.WeekOfYear`, try this function to calculate the ISO weeknumber:

```
//fxISOWeekNum

(theDate as date) =>
let
   a = Date.AddDays(theDate,-1),
   b = Date.DayOfWeek(a,Day.Sunday),
   c = Date.AddDays(theDate,-b + 3),
   d2 = #date(Date.Year(c),1,3),
   IWN  =  Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From(theDate)-Number.From(d2) + Date.DayOfWeek(d2,Day.Sunday)+6,7)

in
    IWN
```